# Using custom fonts and recoloring for MapboxGl markers

Tags: css, icons, zurb-foundation, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to use Foundation Icon Fonts or Font Awesome icons as the markers on the map for MapboxGL, basically embedding HTML like

```
"<i class="fi-marker"></i>"
```

into the "marker-symbol" field? Also, is there a "icon-color" or "marker-color" field for changing the color of the marker in that case? That would make it very easy to customize the color of the marker.

For mapboxgl's own marker symbols, I couldn't find a way to custom color them, I've seen "default_marker" (blue) and "secondary_marker" (red), but I want to use more colors to distinguish between certain locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to create HTML markers on a GL map. The map is rendered in WebGL and there is no easy way to embed HTML within WebGL.

You [can use custom icons in `symbol` layers](https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers) but they cannot be recolored as if by `icon-color` or `marker-color`. You will need to generate all colored images ahead of time.